# La modal de bootstrap la tapa el menu

Tags: bootstrap

tengo un problema con mi modal de Bootstrap, lo que pasa es que la modal la esta tapando mi menu y no se como pasar la modal al frente o el menu pasarlo a tras. Gracias y espero que me puedan ayudar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pudieras incluir un __[mcve]__ sería ideal. Puedes usar el _snippet_ ejecutable en tu misma pregunta.  Sin datos de qué estás haciendo tu pregunta podría ser cerrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede eso debido a que el menú contiene un `z-index` mas alto que el `modal` y el `backdrop`. Lo que te sugiero es que cambies el `z-index` del menú o bien del `backdrop` y `modal`

Para establecer el `z-index` del `modal` y `backdrop` puedes ponerlo siguiente:

```
.backdrop{
  z-index:1050 !important;//cambiar el valor por uno mas alto
}
.modal{
  z-index:1050 !important;//cambiar el valor por el mismo del backdrop + 1
}
```

en caso de solo establecer el `z-index` del menú usa lo siguiente:

```
.navbar{
  z-index: 1 !important;
  //usar el mas pequeño, cuidando que no se valla a ocultar en otro contenido de la pagina
}
```